# Check the validity of a weblink

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform I'm using to connect to server via the use of a php script held online. Ive made it so my program can store this address within the settings of the winform itself like so:

```
http://server.webhost.com/file/uploadimage.html
```

Then when to pass this address to my program I simply call the following:

```
Settings.Default.ServerAddress;
```

Then to send my file to the server I have the following method which calls looks like this:

```
UploadToServer.HttpUploadFile(Settings.Default.ServerAddress , sfd.FileName.ToString(), "file", "image/jpeg", nvc);
```

However I have no idea of how to check to make sure that the address entered is actually valid. Is there a best practice to achieve that?

Comment: What does "valid" mean? The only way to fully verify that is to try uploading, unless you're using some kind of protocol.

Comment: Do you mean valid as in formatted correctly, or valid in that it points to an operating webpage?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish here, my thinking is "That's what exception handling is for". Consider just performing the transfer within a `try` block then handling any issues in the corresponding `catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way to make sure that a URL is working is to actually request it for content, you can make it better by placing a request of type `HEAD` only. Like

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("yoururl") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "HEAD"; //Get only the header information -- no need to download any content
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        if (statusCode >= 100 && statusCode < 400) //Good requests
        {
        }
        else //if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode <= 510) //Server Errors
        {
            //Hard to reach here since an exception would be thrown 
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //handle exception
    //something wrong with the url
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Uri (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to parse it.  You'll get an exception if it's not "valid".  But as the other's who commented state, depending what kind of "valid" you want, this may or may not be good enough for what you are doing.